# Copying Joomla to Parallels Plesk IIS server gives internal server error

Tags: php, joomla, permissions, plesk

Have been stuck with this problem for a few days now.

I am trying to copy my Joomla website from localhost to my Parallels Plesk IIS server. I copied the website into a directory on the server (not the root). I have imported the MySQL already and it works fine and can access the administrator page just fine. However, when I try to view the home page (index.php) it gives me an "internal server error".

I have searched through all the Joomla forums and nothing has helped me. I have tried changing the permissions to 777, checking the log files and changing the configuration file but have not been able to find the problem.

Please if anyone could help I would be really greatfull! This is driving me crazy!

Comment: check you .htaccess file too

Comment: It's a windows server? What is the plesk version, 12.5?

Comment: Yes it is a windows server. There were some modules that were causing the server to throw that error. I am still having problem tracking exactly what it is. But is seems like all modules that require jQuery are throwing that error. 

The modules for me that are not working are "SCLogin", "News Show SP2" and "BT Content Slider". After disabling them my home page works fine. 

Now I am trying to pin point why they are causing my site to crash. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

There was a plugin that I installed that was somehow throwing an error when trying to execute jQuery (Fast Social Share plugin).

I uninstalled it and its working perfectly now!

Thanks!!!